# Lisp: expand property name in macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, clisp, gnu-common-lisp

Consider this property list:

```
(defvar *some-variable* (list :foo "fooval" :bar "barval"))
```

This simple call:

```
(getf *some-variable* :foo)
```

yields `"fooval"` as expected. I define a macro which is supposed to do the same except that I can pass the name of any property to retrieve:

```
(defmacro my-macro (property-name)
    `(getf *some-variable* :,property-name))
```

Unfortunately, calling it like this:

```
(my-macro 'foo)
```

results in `FOO`. Why?

Comment: Use MACROEXPAND to debug this.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I've already tried that but I'm still clueless.

Comment: And what did it return?

Comment: @RainerJoswig:
`FOO ;`
`NIL`

Comment: no, what did macroexpand of the form return?

Comment: No-one yet seems to have pointed out that `:,x` is, essentially, a syntax error.  You can't use `,` to splice things inside the syntax of a symbol: this is as bogus as if you said `make-,foo` to try and create some symbol.  If you want to construct symbols in specific packages you have to do more work than that.

Comment: @tfb: CLISP sees `:,x` as `:||` plus `,x` . LispWorks OTOH reports a syntax error.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks!  I should have tried before posting my comment: I think I'd assumed that the conforming interpretation was CLISP's, but I'm actually not sure, perhaps it's just not clear if it is legal or not.  What it *doesn't* do is what OP wanted, obviously.  This kind of error tends to come from using 'language in a string' macro systems like (shudder) Jinja2.

Comment: @tfb: I haven't thought about whether it is legal or not. Yes, it's clear though that it would not do the intended thing. But this type of problem (comma operator in a symbol) comes up from time to time here on Stackoverflow. There is some expectation from beginners, that this might work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just check it out yourself:

```lisp
(macroexpand-1 '(my-macro 'foo))
; ==> (getf *some-variable* :|| 'foo) ;
T
```

The [documentation for `getf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm) says that if you give it a 4th argument it is the value when the key is not found. Since `:||` (the empty symbol in the keyword package) doesn't exist it returns the supplied default `foo`.

So here is a function that does what you want:

```lisp
(defun get-field (name)
 (getf *some-variable* 
       (intern (symbol-name name) "KEYWORD")))

(defparameter *test* 'foo)
(get-field *test*)
; ==> "fooval"
```

The only reason to make it a macro is to make it syntax and the main difference between syntax and a function is that the arguments are not evaluated.

```lisp
(defmacro get-mfield (name)
  `(get-field ',name))

(get-mfield foo)
; ==> "fooval"

(get-mfield *test*)
; ==> nil
```

You get to come with literals bare, but you loose the feature that `*test*` is regarded as a variable and not the key `:*test*`